# Why do we even use a model class in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, model

I have gone through a number of videos and tutorials for understanding the difference between Model And Controller.
So what i understood is like controller is the medium between our view and Model , it captures the action performed on the UI and calls the appropriate model class, receives back the model object from the model class and send it to the view given by the view resolver.

Now my question is why do we make the controller to send the request to a model , why do we even need a different class(model). Can't we do the same thing in controller itself ?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to test and maintain / change / exchange.

The general idea behind MVC is so that you have different modules of your app each with their own function. This way you get less coupling and higher cohesion - coupling refers to classes connected so tightly that, if you decide to change one single variable in one single class you would have to go through your code and check everywhere for exceptions/bugs etc. Cohesion on the other hand refers to having smaller portions of code in separate classes, which depend on nothing else, thus when you change them you can be sure nothing else breaks.

Of course, this can not be explained in a few lines. The best thing you can do is to start writing code, some basic app and see the how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Really what you say you can do, but it is a bad practice, the MVC is made to separate the layers of development, thus to make it neater develop for all, it must meet a standard for good understanding and management not only but you Developer ...